# How to test UILocalNotification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, debugging, uilocalnotification

I would like to test how my app behaves when the app is quit and the user taps a notification in notification center so that my app is launched. In `- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can check for the key `UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];` but how can I debug this?

If i start running the app in Xcode then I quit the app it will lose the connection to Xcode.

Comment: Keep your application running in background connected to xcode in debug mode and let one local notification arrive, then go to notification center and click on that notification and didReceiveLocalNotification function will be called. The only difference between local notification arriving when application is completely closed is that you have to write code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveLocalNotification is not called. Hope this info helps you..

Answer (score 13):

If you set your Xcode Scheme to launched manually (Edit Scheme > Run > Info), then you can stop running your app after you've scheduled your `UILocalNotification`.

Then if you run your application again, it won't launch until you launch it from the simulator/device.

Then you could wait for the notification to fire and click the notification which then launches your app (manually!). That way you can debug that `UILocalNotification` from the `launchOptions` of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Just note that for debugging, you'll probably want to schedule your `UILocalNotification` for a date about 10 seconds or so in the future, it's always a pain to debug time related stuff.

Good luck.

Comment: For xcode 10 setting it manually is selecting `Wait for executable to be launched`

Answer (score 0):

the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method will not be called until you launch the app. But closing your app does NOT make your app loses its connection with xcode, as your app goes in background.

Maybe i missed something, but you actually can run your app in your device and then proceed as you wish.

Also you can try this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if the log are still not working.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"options" message:[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    return YES;
```

Comment: Xcode Schemes allow you to launch app manually or automatically when you run your app from Xcode. If you choose manually you could then wait for a notification to appear on device/simulator and click through to launch your app and thus debug from the launchOptions. See my answer above. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21306204/662605

Answer (score 0):

Keep your application running in background connected to `xcode` in **debug mode** and let one local notification arrive, then go to notification center and click on that notification and `didReceiveLocalNotification:` function will be called.

The only difference between local notification arriving when application is completely closed is that you have to write code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (you can copy paste same code you have written for `didReceiveLocalNotification:` function) and `didReceiveLocalNotification:` is not called.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: So there's really no **real** way to test it in `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ?

Comment: If you have device then you can check device log which is in Organiser of xcode

Comment: You could just launch the app manually (edit your scheme). Be sure your app isn't running in anyway when you click on the notification and your app will launch from the notification and all hooked up into Xcode. See my answer above http://stackoverflow.com/a/21306204/662605

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a stupid answer. :)

I usually put a **UIAlertView** there. And set the text in alertview depending on the local notification.

Another is quit the app. Put some NSLog's in **applicationDidFinishLaunching**. Quit the App. Go to **Xcode->Organiser**. Then select your device under **Devices** tab. Select the options **Console**. You can see the logs there.

Hope this may help.